# Open cart category |Home| not redirecting to correct page

Tags: php, url, redirect, url-rewriting, opencart

I have added a category |Home| however when hitting the link it redirects to index.php?route=product/category&path=% How would i redirect to the index of my site?

Comment: Show us your code or we can't help. We are not psychic.

Comment: its standard Opencart Configuration With Default Templates. So source is available at  http://code.google.com/p/opencart/source/checkout

Comment: The category name is "Home"? And do you have SEO links enabled?

Comment: Yes I Do. SEO links are enabled @Cleverbot

Comment: I think what is happening is that Opencart already has $home and they have protected against names overlapping and causing problems with existing names. Why don't you try naming it "Home-1" and if that works we can safely assume that you will need to rename your category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So never really came to much of a conclusion but i did add a link manually to the navigation bar. All working now. Thanks for taking the time to help